# Use pg_query_params array placeholders for searching multiple columns

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, placeholder

I pass two different values into the file, one which the user entered and the other which is selected from a predefined set of values in a drop down menu, which is the one i'm having trouble with.

When using a single placeholder for the query it works,for example:

```
$result = pg_query_params($con, "SELECT * FROM chemsub WHERE name like $1", array("%".$_REQUEST['term']."%"));
```

I want to alter the query so the user can change which column they are searching i can't seem to get it to work, here is what i have

```
$result = pg_query_params($con, "SELECT * FROM chemsub WHERE $1 like $2", array($_REQUEST['dropdown'],"%".$_REQUEST['term']."%"));
```

I know the correct value is being passed into the file with the correct spelling matching a column name in the database but for some reason it returns no rows.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have params in place of identifiers. If you want to have a dynamic column being queried again you can either prepare the query text in php or have the sql look like `($1 = 'foo' AND foo LIKE $2) OR ($1 = 'bar' ANd bar LIKE $2`.`

Comment: thanks for the answer, although i have tried what you suggested and can't get it to work either way, any other suggestions?

Comment: @syn_p What do you mean by "Can't get it to work"? I can't say anything until I see the query and the error it returns.

Comment: The query doesn't return an error, it just doesn't work as intended. 

Instead of returning the number of rows (this will be extended to returning the actual results, but one step at a time), it is completing the query and returning 'Rows: 0'.

I have checked what the query is printing by separating it from the pg_query_params, and echo-ing it before calling query_params, and the content is correct (listing the correct column name (as specified by the dropdown list and value entered).

Comment: @syn_p So it seems you just don't have the data that fits it.